# Aggregating and finding the largest value

Tags: r

I have below data frame:

```
df1 <- data.frame(city =c("c1","c2","c3","c2","c1","c2"),people =c(1000,234,678,45,11,100))
```

I try to find total number of people in c1,c2,c3 and select the largest population. I wrote below code:

```
aggregate(city~people, df1, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x)))
```

How can I complete this code to achieve my goal.

(**Note**: my result is like

```
c1: 1011 
c2: 379
```

are the biggest cities .)

Comment: Did you meant `aggregate(people~city, df1, max)` or 
`setDT(df1)[, .SD[which.max(people)] , city]`  `library(data.table)`

Comment: Can you show your expected output in the edit because your grouping variable is 'people' in the code which has only a single observation per group

Comment: @akrun: my result in city1 should be 1011 in city 2 should be 379 and city should be 678 and the biggest city are city 1 and city2. but this a aggregation does not give me the result.

Comment: I guess you want sum, then, i.e. `aggregate(people ~city, df1, sum)`

Comment: @akron: thanks, How can I select the max and min population? can I write function for that and include both operation together?

Comment: You can do `aggregate(people ~city, df1, function(x) c(Sum = sum(x), Min = min(x) , Max = max(x)))` or with `dplyr` ` df1 %>% group_by(city) %>% summarise_at(vars(people), funs(sum, min, max))`

Comment: @akrun I want to find 2 largest cities. the code you wrote has different result. for example city1, and city 2 has the largest population among all the other cities.

Answer (score 1):

tapply is more efficient than aggregate if you don't mind the slight difference in output format that you get, array opposed to data.frame.

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(tapply(df1$people, df1$city, sum), aggregate(people~city, df1, sum))
Unit: microseconds
                               expr     min       lq      mean   median       uq      max neval
  tapply(df1$people, df1$city, sum)  48.283  60.2675   86.4515  68.0010  107.416  258.671   100
 aggregate(people ~ city, df1, sum) 690.907 715.2445 1012.9741 770.7325 1268.336 3853.902   100
```

This code gives you the city names with max and min totals respectively

```
sum_by_city <- tapply(df1$people, df1$city, sum)
names(which.max(sum_by_city))
names(which.min(sum_by_city))
```

Or if you wanted the top 2

```
names(sort(sum_by_city, decreasing = TRUE)[1:2])
```

Comment: if I want to select 2 city with the largest population how can I do that?

Comment: thank you I have one more question if my dataframe is look like: df1 <- data.frame(company=c("c1","c2","c3","c2","c1","c2"),field=c("A","B","C","A","D","C")) how can I do the same action. I want to see for each company, how many fields can be find and then select top 2 companies in each fields.

Comment: I'd suggest updating your question with a more detailed description of what you want to do. What exactly does your full dataframe and target output look like?

Comment: How can I divide my sum in tapply. for eaxample: tapply(df1$employmenttaxes, df1$name, sum **/100**) is definitely wrong